# Алгоритм проверки графов на изоморфизм

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм, графы

Я могу написать только перебор всех биекций. Использовал VF2, но так и не смог понять его полностью и сам написать не смогу. Какие еще есть алгоритмы для проверки графов на изоморфизм? Желательно, чтобы этот алгоритм можно было бы легко модифицировать под свои нужды.

Comment: а какой размер графа примерно?

Comment: @pavel, это не важно. Главное чтобы реализация алгоритма не была очень сложной.

Comment: перебор за N!*N самое простое.

Comment: @pavel, можете написать? а то у меня перебор как-то криво выходит

Answer (score 1):

Самое наивное решение которое только можно придумать. Сложность `O(N!*N^2)`.

```
const int N = 3;

char A[N][N] = { {0,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,0} };
char B[N][N] = { {0,0,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,0} };

int P[N] = {0,1,2};


bool match(){
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
            if (A[i][j] != B[ P[i] ][ P[j] ])
                return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    do {
       if (match()){
          for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
            cout << P[i] << " ";
          return 0;
       }
    } while (next_permutation(P, P+N));
}
```

Comment: А если я знаю заранее, что какие-то вершины могут совпасть при изоморфизме, а какие-то нет. Обычно это значительно уменьшает перебор. Как в этом случае поступить?

Comment: тогда есть смысл полностью сформулировать что известно о графе. Можно значительно ускорить метод match и перебирать (конечно не так красиво будет) не через next_permutation а своим методом.